# Sound over Dockingstation in KDE

Tags: audio, kde, pulseaudio

I just installed Debian on my new Laptop(Lenovo X1) and I would like to use a ThinkPad OneLink Dock. Everything works great (USB, HDMI, Ethernet...) except for the audio.

When I plug in the OneLink and connect my audio system to the dock the sound is still played over the Laptop internal sound. If I right-click on the speaker symbol in the menu bar, I can select a "main channel"(the German original is: "Hauptkanal auswählen") , which lists an entry:

```
ThinkPad OneLink Dock USB Audio Analog Stereo
```

But if I selected nothing changes, the sound is still played over the internal sound sytem.

How do I play sounds over my docking station in KDE?

This is the software I'm using:

Pulseaudio: 5.0-13

Qt: 4.8.6

KDE: 4.14.2

kde4-config: 1.0